# creating an admin's page so that the user can not access other pages

Tags: php

i have been following an online tutorial on how to create a login and logout page in php and mysql,which seemed to be way easy not until i stage where i would like to modify the scripts,i am trying to put an admin's page where the user will have access to some links..i  added a column in my users table called user_level,i want when a user logs in he his user_level is 1 he will access the links in the season.php script but if his user_level is 2 he will be directed to another page...i tried doing this below but its not working

```
if($user_level == 1){

header("Location: links.php");

}
else($user_level == 2){

header("Location: client.php");

}
```

this is my session.php code

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])&&isset($_COOKIE['testsite'])){
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_COOKIE['testsite'];
}

$dir = "profiles/".$_SESSION['name']."/images/";
$open = opendir($dir);

while(($file = readdir($open)) != FALSE){
    if($file!="."&&$file!=".."&&$file!="Thumbs.db"){
        echo "<img border='1' width='70' height='70' src='$dir/$file'>";
    }

}

echo "&nbsp<b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>'s session<br /><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

if($user_level == 1){

header("Location: links.php");

}
else($user_level == 2){

header("Location: client.php");

}
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$user_level` defined?

Comment: What's it doing, and what do you expect it to do? You need an `if` with your `else {}`, e.g. `elseif (logic)` _or_ `else { if (logic) {} }`

Comment: first you must learn, how to use `if/else` conditions. For example in your first code part you must use `else if`, not `else`. Then in your 2th part `!isset(blabla) && !isset(blabla)`. Without syntax you can't move 1 step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong and you should not redirect if you want to show links, it should probably be something like:

```
if($user_level == 1){
  // don't redirect here
  include "links.php";
}
// check the php manual for the correct usage of if / else / elseif
elseif ($user_level == 2){
  header("Location: client.php");
  // terminate the script
  exit;
}
```

Comment: you are right also in second part not equeal operator missed before second `isset()`

Comment: @hakiko To be honest, I did not even look at the second part, but it seems correct for what the OP wants to do; you need the cookie to be set to be able to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when using `header("Location: client.php");` be sure that this is the **first** thing that comes out of your script. You can't dump out a whole html page and then put this at the bottom, it won't redirect.